# Easiest way to show text in gui?

Tags: java

I've seen many posts about it, but it looks complicated. Here is my code, what would be the easiest way to display information on gui textArea?

```
public static void runSystemCommand(String command) {

  String message=null;
  int i=0;
  while (i<1) {     
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s = "";
        // reading output stream of the command
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            //here i dont know what to type..please help
        }
        Thread.sleep(9000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
     i++;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is this about JTextArea, or do you just want something similar to JavaScript's `alert()`?

Comment: `textArea.append(s+"\r\n")` should work for this case?

Comment: Assuming that you already have a reference to your [`TextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), you need something like `txtArea.append(s + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ))`;

Comment: program reads from CMD console , its a ping host program.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be

```
textAreaName.setText(/*What ever you want to display here*/);
```

In your case it would be the following if you wanted to just set the text to `s`:

```
textArea.setText(s + "\n");
```

If you wanted to update the text along with the existing text you would use:

```
textArea.append(s + "\n");
```